# How do I disable the 'Close Window' option in the taskbar?

Tags: c, winapi, mingw32

[image]

How to write a C Code in order to disable the 'Close Window' option in the taskbar?

Compiler: GCC-mingw32

Which API Function should I use?

Thanks.

Comment: Do yoy want to "disable" that option for arbitrary applications, for which you don't have source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the window's message dispatcher process the message `WM_SYSCOMMAND` and filter it out if the message's `wParam` is `SC_CLOSE`.

Let `WndProc` be the windows message handler then the code to do might look like this:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  ...

  switch (message)
  {
    case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
     if (wParam == SC_CLOSE);
       break;

     return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);  

    case ...

  }

  return 0;
}
```

This does **not** remove the "close"-menu item from the application's jump-list (its taskbar's local menu), but **disables** its functionality.